# empty new variable instead adding into existing object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, next.js

I'm adding a new array on callback using props but it is adding an empty variable instead of adding a new array.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    title: "",
    serviceId: "",
    serviceName: "",
    sourceLang: "",
  });

const handleLocalData = (newData): any => {
    console.log("newData from index", newData.destinationLang);
    setData(prev => ({ ...prev, destinationLang: newData.destinationLang }));
  };
```

My return in newData.destinationLang is

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "English",
        "code": "EN",
        "color": "#ccc433"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Italian",
        "code": "IT",
        "color": "#33bacc"
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't see any array here, you're using an object and adding a property to it on the callback.

Comment: On callback, I'm adding array of object to destinationLang

Answer (score 0):

You're setting initial state of `data` as a `object` and then you try to assign `array` to it.
Here's a working example:

```
const App = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  
  const newData1 = {'destinationLang': [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "English",
        "code": "EN",
        "color": "#ccc433"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Italian",
        "code": "IT",
        "color": "#33bacc"
    }
]};

const handleLocalData = (newData) => {
    setData(prev => {
      console.log(prev)
      if(prev !== null)
        return ({ destinationLang: [ ...prev.destinationLang, ...newData.destinationLang ]});
      else
        return ({ destinationLang: newData.destinationLang })
    })
};

  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={() => handleLocalData(newData1)}>Add data</a>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: Bro @peter, this is not working for me, still creating empty value. my useState is like this.

`
const [data, setData] = useState({
    title: "",
    serviceId: "",
    serviceName: "",
    sourceLangId: "",
    destinationLang: "",
})
`

Comment: Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-heyrovsky-u18hw4?file=/src/App.js